# JSON: Cannot read property '0' of undefined

Tags: javascript, php, json, html-table

I'm trying to parse JSON data to a html table, but I get:

> "Cannot read property '0' of undefined"

```
<?php

$idmatchs = "bGdzkiUVu,bCrAvXQpO,b4I6WYnGB,bMgwck80h";

$exploded = explode(",", $idmatchs);
$count = count($exploded);

?>

<script>
$.get( "obte2.php?id=f_1_0_-3_es_1", function ( data ) {
    var json = eval ("(" + data + ")");

    var matchids = "<?php echo $idmatchs ?> ";
    var ids =  matchids.split(",");

    for (i=0; i < ids.length; i++) {
        $( "#"+ids[i] + " #est" ).html( json.ids[i][0].EST );   
    }

});

</script>


<table class="tg">

 <?php

 for( $i= 0 ; $i < $count ; $i++ ){

    echo '<tr id="'.$exploded[$i].'">';
    echo '<td id="est"></td>';
    echo '</tr>';

  }

 ?>
 </table>
```

Chrome highlights this line:

```
$( "#"+ids[i] + " #est" ).html( json.ids[i][0].EST );
```

In fact, if I replace ids[i] for any id, the code works perfectly.

```
$( "#"+ids[i] + " #est" ).html( json.bGdzkiUVu[0].EST );
```

The JSON file is this:

```
{
"bGdzkiUVu": [
    {
        "INI": "1437150600",
        "EST": "PROG",
        "AC": "1",
        "LCL": "Amberg",
        "AX": "0",
        "LIN": "AMB",
        "AE": "Amberg",
        "WU": "amberg",
        "OA": "team",
        "WN": "MEM",
        "VST": "Memmingen",
        "WV": "memmingen",
        "OB": "team",
        "AN": "y"
    }
],
"bCrAvXQpO": [
    {
        "INI": "1437150600",
        "EST": "PROG",
        "AC": "1",
        "LCL": "SpVgg Bayreuth",
        "AX": "0",
        "WN": "SCH",
        "VST": "Schalding",
        "WV": "schalding",
        "OB": "team",
        "LIN": "SPV",
        "AE": "SpVgg Bayreuth",
        "WU": "spvgg-bayreuth",
        "OA": "team",
        "AN": "y"
    }
],
"b4I6WYnGB": [
    {
        "INI": "1437152400",
        "EST": "PROG",
        "AC": "1",
        "LCL": "1860 Munich II",
        "AX": "0",
        "LIN": "186",
        "AE": "1860 Munich II",
        "WU": "1860-munich",
        "OA": "team",
        "WN": "BUR",
        "VST": "Burghausen",
        "WV": "burghausen",
        "OB": "team",
        "AN": "y"
    }
],
"bMgwck80h": [
    {
        "INI": "1437152400",
        "EST": "PROG",
        "AC": "1",
        "LCL": "Buchbach",
        "AX": "0",
        "LIN": "BUC",
        "AE": "Buchbach",
        "WU": "buchbach",
        "OA": "team",
        "WN": "RAI",
        "VST": "Rain/Lech",
        "WV": "rain-lech",
        "OB": "team",
        "AN": "y"
    }
]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're asking JS to look for `ids[i]` which literally evaluates to `ids[0]` or `ids[1]` when you're actually looking for `ids.bGdzkiUVu`.  Rather than using the index, you need to be looking them up by key.

For example:

```
Object.keys(ids).forEach(function (key) {
    // do something with ids[key]
});
```

Comment: I put your code instead the for loop and I still cant make it work. Why "ids[i]" works in the JQuery Selector, but does not works when i try to set as html?